# Which Hindu scripture talks about weapons and mythical objects? Please guide me with links to apt books

Tags: weapon, brahmastra

I want to know about mythical bows and weapons like Brahmastra, etc. So please tell which scripture talks about divine weapons, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Are you asking what scriptures contain information on how to use Astras?  Or are you asking what scriptures describe people using Astras in the past?

Comment: Many scriptures talk about them not just one.

Comment: Thank you Keshav sir , i want to know about the description of these weapons . Please guide me

Comment: @VishweswarEswaran Again, do you want description of how to use them, or description of what they looked like, or description of stories where they were used, or what?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Sir i want description on how they look and what they can do, not the way to invoke them

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Sir i want to know their description on how they look and what are their powers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mythological_objects_(Hindu_mythology) - This is brief list